# I just installed MacTeX and cannot get a new .cls to run correctly

Tags: errors

I'm new to LaTex so forgive me if I use some incorrect language here. I'm trying to install a new .cls file from AIAA and have read from the LaTeX wiki that .cls files should go under Users/username/Library/texmf/, however when I go to 'Library' I don't see a sub folder labeled 'texmf'. I have installed the latest version of MacTeX.

Is there another location I should place the .cls file in my directory for it to run properly? This is the error I get when I try to run it now

! LaTeX Error: File `new-aiaa.cls' not found.Type X to quit or  to proceed,or enter new name. (Default extension: cls)Enter file name:! Emergency stop. \usepackage

Comment: The folder is not created by the MacTeX installer. The actual folder for the class file is ~/Library/texmf/tex/latex and you need to create the nested folders texmf/tex/latex inside ~/Library. Note that ~/Library is the Library folder in your HOME folder, NOT the one in the root of you hard drive. Finder normally hides that folder in recent OS versions. To Open ~/Library click on the Go menu in Finder and hold down Opt key so  new menu item to go there will appear.

Comment: Here's a script you can run on your Mac to generate the correct local tree with its internal structure: https://msu.edu/~amunn/latex/make-local-texmf.zip. See [How to have local package override default package](//tex.stackexchange.com/a/8359) for how the folder should be set up if you do it manually.

Comment: You can also just put the `.cls` file into the same directory as your `.tex` file if you only need it for a particular document.